# get Double.NOTANUMBER from default(T) when T=double, is it possible?

Tags: c#

I need help for a problem in my application.
In my application , I need to use double.NotANumber when I make Default(T) and the type of my generic is double. But what I get is "0.0". 
Is they a way to get the value I need????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `default(double)` will always be 0, and there's nothing you can do to change that.

The closest you could come would be to write a separate static method:

```
public static T GetDefaultValue<T>()
{
    return typeof(T) == typeof(double) ? (T)(object) double.NaN : default(T);
}
```

You'd then need to call that method instead of using `default(T)`. It's pretty nasty though :(

Comment: Thanks for your answers.Jon your answer resolve my problem . But I just want to understant why you cast double.NaN  to Object before cast it in  generic type "T"?

Comment: And is there a explain for why we can't change return value of default ?

Comment: @Wilfrid: The casting rules around generics are quite tricky. I'm not going to claim to understand all the design decisions - just that they're necessary. As for why you can't *change* the default - `default(T)` always returns the "zero value" - i.e. the value you get from wiping memory to all bits being 0. That's how arrays are created etc. It's cheap and uniform.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if thinking in terms of `T=Nullable<double>` would help your processing here; then `default(T)` is `null` (or at least, null-ish). Still not quite `NaN`, but closer than `0`, and it extends naturally to all value types.